# I am trying to commit a large set of source codes. Why is txn props file missing

Tags: svn, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, commit, collabnet

I am currently running Ubuntu 12.04 VM running inside Parallels Desktop Build 9.0.24237, with SVN Client Version 1.8.9 running. I have tried committing my codes to a Windows 7 SVN Server, running collabnet subversion edge 4.0.1-3680.114 (SVN Version is 1.8.1-3680.114).

This commit was done within an intranet environment, with my computer and SVN server running on the same network. When committing this large set of files, I ultimately get the error seen in the attached image. What could be the cause of this failure? When committing 1 or 2 files at a time, there is no issue. **However, when committing a folder with many subfolders and files, this happens.** It takes more than an hour to commit this code. I am using the command line to execute this.

```
svn --version
svn, version 1.8.9 (r1591380)
compiled May  1 2014, 13:43:56 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

[image: Missing props file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What protocol are you using to communicate to the server?  http, svn or svn+ssh?  I only have experience with this error in http (though the others should be similar).

I'm pretty sure that the file error is a cascade from the real problem, which is the connection timeout.  Take a look at the server's logs and you should see some mention of a timeout.  When you commit a large checkin (in my experience the number of files can be as much of a problem as the size of the files), svn has to construct a "transaction" object on the server, if that takes longer than the server's timeout period, Apache can break the connection before it is done.

Increasing the "Timeout" (or perhaps "KeepAliveTimeout", I cannot remember, exactly) setting (and restarting Apache) should fix this.

The other protocols should have some similar timeout settings which can be tweaked.

Comment: Thanks. I believe this is the problem :)